# How to build an array copyto method

Tags: c#, arrays

I wrote the following code using Array.copy()

```
  public void CopyTo(int[] array, int[] array2, int startat)
    {
        Array.Copy(array2, startat, array, 0, array.Length);

        foreach (int number in array2)
        {
            Console.Write(number + "\t");
        }
    }
```

How can I write my own copyto method that do the same thing as Array.copy()?

Comment: Why do you want/need to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy one array to another at certain index c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460384/copy-one-array-to-another-at-certain-index-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible? It's the same question by the same user, edited by the same admin.  Technically the other one is a dupe of this one, since this one was first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the for loop and copy the value of each position in first array to second array

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array2[i] = array[i];
}
```