# copy one array to another at certain index c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to build this copy method using for loops, so far I wrote the code below that copy array1 to array2

```
public static void CopyTo1(int[] array1, int[] array2, int startat)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
           array1[i] = array2[i];
           Console.Write(array2[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

how can i make "startat" determine in what index the copying shall start?

```
int [] array1 = new int [3] {4, 5, 6};
int [] array2 = new int [6] {1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0};
startat=3;
// array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void CopyTo1(int[] array1, int[] array2, int startat)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
           array2[startat] = array1[i];
            startat++;
           Console.Write(array2[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```